# Codename One - Calendar component, change month event handling

Tags: codenameone

I want to handle events of switching months in Codename One's calendar.

In Calendar component 'change month' is triggering listeners attached by addActionListener(ActionListener l) method. But this is also triggering when a day is being selected. How can I distinguish between these two events?

Answer (score 0):

If you override the day button click event you can get an event to indicate date selection. You can also use the `DataChangeListener` for fine grained events.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want the date selection event on day button, only month/year change event on month/year selection. DataChangedListener is not being triggered at all.

Comment: You will need to filter this in the reverse order. You can also take the source of the Calendar and work from that as it was designed for relatively simplistic use cases.